# Can't use HDD alongside SSD

Tags: boot

I've installed Ubuntu on a SSD, how do I lock the SSD so I cant be used and how do I make my HDD mass storage. My HDD is not showing up in the Ubuntu home finder so I can only save documents to the ssd. I only want the ssd for the software. How can I make the HDD visible and the default drive for Ubuntu. The ssd is a 120gb so if there is any free space I'd like to partition it so I can keep the free space and lock the os side. I don't know how. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> My HDD is not showing up in the Ubuntu home finder so I can only save documents to the ssd. I only want the ssd for the software. How can I make the HDD visible and the default drive for Ubuntu.

Install gparted (`sudo apt-get install gparted`) and run it with root privileges, `sudo gparted`. Find your missing disk in the drop down in the top right. If it is not formatted, format it with ext4. In order to help you further you would need to supply some more information (screenshots, perhaps), but after formatting it should show up on your desktop, and upon clicking it Ubuntu should mount it for you.

You can also use gparted to partition your SSD in the way you describe.